# No completa el ciclo foreach

Tags: c#

Estoy haciendo un método para invertir palabras que contengan 5 o mas letras. El problema que tengo es que si mi cadena tiene mas de 2 palabras, se sale del ciclo. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? (Es un ejercicio de Codewars, estoy aprendiendo apenas)

```
public static string SpinWords(string sentence)
{
    string[] words = sentence.Split();

    foreach (string word in words)
    {
        if (word.Length < 5)
        {
            char[] charArray = word.ToCharArray();
            return new string(charArray);
        }

        if (word.Length >= 5)
        {          
            char[] charArray = word.ToCharArray();
            Array.Reverse(charArray);
            return new string(charArray);
        }         
    }

    return words.ToString();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por supuesto, tu problema inmediato, en cuanto al porqué tu ciclo termina prematuramente, es porque usas `return` dentro del ciclo.

Como específica la documentación para [`return`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/1h3swy84.aspx):

> La instrucción `return` ***termina la ejecución del método*** en el que aparece y devuelve el control al método que realizó la llamada.

**Otros problemas**

1. Debido a que tu sentencia final es `return words.ToString();`, asumo que tu intención era modificar el arreglo `words` en tu ciclo. Pero no lo haces en ninguna parte, ni entiendo cómo pensabas lograrlo.
2. Relacionado al punto anterior, el uso de un `foreach` probablemente no sea adecuado si tu intención era de ir modificando cada elemento de `words` en tu ciclo. El uso de un ciclo `for` sería mejor.
3. Si no tienes intención de cambiar las palabras con menos de 5 letras, entonces no necesitas una condición para ese caso.
4. `words.ToString();` no es la manera correcta de juntar las palabras en el arreglo `words`. Mas bien, deberías usar [`String.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Ejemplo que sí funciona**

Poniendo en práctica los puntos anteriores, te propongo un ejemplo simplificado que puedes analizar para ver cómo funciona:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

// ...

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(SpinWords("Buen día roñes Alex"));
}

private static string SpinWords(string sentence)
{
    string[] words = sentence.Split();

    for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
    {
        if (words[i].Length >= 5)
        {
            words[i] = new string(words[i].Reverse().ToArray());
        }
    }

    return string.Join(" ", words);
}
```

**Resultado**

> Buen día señor Alex

Comment: Me sirvió a la perfección! Muchísimas gracias por su asistencia a todos!

Answer (score 2):

Tú codigo no completa el foreach debido a que cada vez que entra en un if (y entra siempre porque si no cumple el primero, cumple el segundo) **hay un return que lo que hace es salir del método**. Aun no entiendo que es lo que quieres hacer con ese codigo, pero si tú pregunta es "porque no completa el foreach", esta es la respuesta.

Comment: Es un ejercicio que estoy haciendo ya que estoy apenas aprendiendo a programar. Muchas gracias por tus comentarios!

Answer (score 0):

modifica tu codigo intentando no usar toda parte la palabra reservada return, te aconsejo siempre que uses esa palabra (return) utilices al final de tu  funcion.

ahora veo que tu funcion se sale por que haces mal uso del return

Comment: Lo tomare en cuenta para futuros ejercicios que realice, muchas gracias por tu ayuda!